# Update all dependant js when json data changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some json with several objects that looks like this:

```
data =[{"itemID":"195","area":"home","note":"fix","date":1481200571},{"itemID":"205","area":"work","note":"drop off","date":1481203571},{"itemID":"207","area":"home","note":"find it","date":1481204571}];
```

Dependent on that data are a number of charts and js queries/manipulations (for loops, filtered arrays and such). What is the easiest/best way to have all the other items change/update when the json data changes (adding or removing records)?

What should be the standard practice here? I don't want to force a page reload, I just want all the other info to update when the source data changes. No server roundtrips should be necessary, this will entirely involve manipulating data on the client end after initial download.

Comment: are you open to using an external library ? angularjs may be?

Comment: unfortunately not for this project, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: NP, If the data is being manipulated and you know when it ends, you could create your own global/window event and raise it when the manipulation is finished. The event will need to be handled by your function where the graph/chart will render itself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events . But what/which event takes priority will depend on the data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this to work the way I wanted, here is what I did:

Since filtering all the data would be via a dropdown selection (daterange), I wrote the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    

jQuery('select#dfilter').on('change', function (e) {

var origdata = json;
var optionSelected = jQuery("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
if (jQuery('select#dfilter').val() == 'week') {
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);
} else if (jQuery('select#dfilter').val() == 'month') {
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 30);
} else {
var startDate = new Date("2016-11-01");
}

var endDate = new Date();
var data = origdata.filter(function (d, i) {
var pubDate = new Date(d.date * 1000);
    return pubDate >= startDate && pubDate <= endDate;
})

// All other items filter by "data" already filtered above, such as:

var numFIX = data.reduce(function(n, data) {
    return n + (data.note("fix"));
}, 0);

// Then draw my charts etc based on "data"

}); //end select on change

//make initial value load when doc ready
jQuery( "select#dfilter" ).trigger( 'change' ); 

}); // end document ready
```

If someone has a better way or some tips, I am all ears, but this seems to work well so far.

Answer (score -1):

You should compare the newest data to the old one and whenever you encounter a change you manipulate you page content by updating the data using javascript only without the need of reloading.

examples of comparing is like :

- number of items changed.
- any-data regarding an item changed.

so depending on the scenario you will either add a new element with the new item using plain javascript only or just updating the old displayed data.

Comment: so the question is, what do I use to bind/check for changes on all of my various sub js (about 10 of them)? Ideally I just want to change the data source and have all other items update automatically.

Comment: unfortunatelly you need to do this manualy for each individual item and please can you clarify what you mean by saying data source ??

Comment: The data source is, as I mentioned above, the json. It will change (via my manipulations) and I want all dependant data to change with it.